# Google Sheets/QUERY/Query to count with criteria from another sheet

Tags: google-sheets

Trying to Perform a Count of specific values across 3 ranges from another Google Sheets Doc.

Answered below.

Comment: Share a sample copy of workbook here.

Comment: Use [tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, do note that [your email address can be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/). You may also try the [Blank sheet maker here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=iferror(index(query({IMPORTRANGE(Source!B2,"TESTING!A2:C")},"select count(Col1) where Col1 = 'John' and Col2 = 1 and Col3 = date '2022-6-30'"),2),0)
```

[image]